# JavaScript code is working in IE and Safari VERISION 323,but not working in Safari version 5

Tags: javascript, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript works on Safari 3 but not on newer versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174478/javascript-works-on-safari-3-but-not-on-newer-versions)

Hi,the following code is working in Safari 322 version,but not working in Safari version 5.I hope that you can solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

```
function loadframe(){
        var iframeEl = document.getElementById("ifrm");
        if(!iframeEl)
        {

            var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.innerHTML = '<iframe id="ifrm" width="80" height="80" src=\'<!--EP CLASS="com.epiphany.presentation.ServerURLWriter" ACTION="campaign_segment_load" TEMPLATE="campaign\\campaign_segments" -->\' onload="dw_display(\'ifrm\',\'segmentspn\')" ></iframe>';

            document.body.appendChild(el);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```